# Extra scrollbar when body height is 100vh

Tags: html, css, background, scrollbar

Here's what I did to set a background on the web page:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(white, tan);
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

Two questions:

1. Is it the right approach to add a background to your page?
2. How should I get rid of the unwanted scrollbar?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `overflow:hidden` to body to hide the scrollbar.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

body tag by default margin 8px for top, bottom, left, right. And h1 tag by default margin-top and margin-bottom 21.440px or 0.67em 
so  you need to set the body margin:0 and h1 margin:0 or margin-top:0

if you want to set only background color for the whole body its fine. if you want to know more about background property then read this [CSS background Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
  margin:0;
}
h1{
 margin-top:0;
   
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do but you can try "overflow : hidden" like this :

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Mostafa Baezid said, there are default margins of `body`.

Also, due to *margin collasping* on the vertical axis, you need to ensure that the topmost or downmost element's margin doesn't collapse, rendering the margin out of the parent.

What's more, `100vh != 100%` as for some mobile broswers. The menu bar of mobile browsers takes up some space and `100vh` doesn't reduce that space.

So what to do:

1. Remove `body` margin (`margin-top` and `margin-bottom` would be enough)
2. Remove the topmost element's `margin-top` and the downmost element's `margin-bottom`. (you can use `padding` instead)
3. Use `height: 100%` instead of `height: 100vh;` for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs a quick remedy, my solution is simple: Downsize from the height of 100vh to the height of 80vh got rid of the vertical scroll bar. Note: I tried other suggestions but none worked for me.