# The Canvas Background and the HTML <body> Element

Tags: html, css, background, specifications

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#body-background):

> It is recommended that authors of HTML documents specify the canvas background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element.

But it doesn't say what advantages it has. Why does the spec recommend this?

P.S. It crossed my mind when I saw [Extra scrollbar when body height is 100vh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42980139/4351667): isn't it better to simply give the background to the `html` element instead?

Comment: Related: [Should global css styles be set on the html element or the body element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565942/should-global-css-styles-be-set-on-the-html-element-or-the-body-element)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prior to CSS, backgrounds were specified by adding the `background` and `bgcolor` attributes to the `body` element in HTML (along with the likes of `text`, `link`, `alink`, `vlink`, `leftmargin`, `marginwidth`, `topmargin` and `marginheight`).

CSS-compliant browsers convert these presentational attributes into the appropriate style rules, placed as author-level presentational hints with just less precedence than author-level `*` rules. More on this in [css-cascade-3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#preshint) and [HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-page). Namely, the `background` and `bgcolor` attributes are converted to `background-image` and `background-color` declarations respectively, for the `body` element.

So, the recommendation that authors specify the canvas background for the `body` element and not the `html` element was made to ease migration of legacy HTML documents from presentational attributes on the `body` element to CSS. Normally if you have control of both the markup and CSS the first thing you'd probably want to do is get rid of the presentational attributes. But you don't *have* to do so right off the bat; you can just add a `background` declaration specific to the `body` element, and it will seamlessly replace the entire page background (as described in the spec link in the question) as specified by the presentational attributes, with no further action necessary:

```css
/* The bgcolor attribute is equivalent to a

body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

rule at this position in the stylesheet,
except with less precedence than a * rule.
The following rule will override it as a
normal part of the cascade. */

body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor=#FFFFFF>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  <p>This page was once white...
  <p>... now it's yellow!
```

If you add it to the `html` element instead, you'll end up with *two* backgrounds:

```css
/*
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
*/

html {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor=#FFFFFF>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  <p>This page was once white...
  <p>... wait, what?
```

If you're aware of the `body` element having a `bgcolor` attribute, this does have the advantage of serving as a visual reminder to you to get rid of the attribute. But if that doesn't occur to you right away, you'll probably be left [flummoxed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body).

Of course, if you're authoring new documents then this simply becomes a matter of tradition (which ties in to the whole "ease of migration" thing). There's nothing stopping you from applying backgrounds to *both* `html` and `body` for interesting effects, though even that has largely been superseded by the ability to add multiple background layers to one element and is only really necessary if you need to support older browsers. More on this in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of preference actually, this is why it is *recommended* rather than being forced as a strict rule.

The `body` tag being a descendant of the `html` tag overrides the `html` properties - being `background` otherwise.

However, since all browsers give a margin to `body` **by default**, creating a border between the `body` and the browser window (although we are used to resetting this margin to 0), I guess this ...*border* was meant to be visible, so using a background on the HTML would make this *border* invisible to users. Given this fact and since all content is contained inside the `body` tag, the *recommendation* was provided by spec.

However, nowadays the `body` tag is usually reset to 0 by almost everyone so using it on either `html` or `body` tag makes no difference and each case provides no advantages compared to the other.

Comment: "The body tag being a descendant of the html tag overrides the html properties - being background otherwise." Can you rephrase? I think you might be alluding to the fact that applying a background to body causes it to paint the entire canvas instead of just the body element - unless you're actually saying that the body background does override the html background, which isn't telling the whole story.

Comment: "margin to body ... creating a border ... I guess this ...border was meant to be visible" It's called a margin and not a border for a reason. It's only supposed to be visible as a gap. It's a relic from a time when web pages were just online text documents (hence "web *pages*"), visually spacing the content from the browser window. Applying a background to either html *or* body (but not both) will have the same, intended results as long as you leave the body margins intact. So whether the default margins are preserved or not really doesn't affect the conclusion here.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be quicker, because BoltClock's one and the spec explain it minutely.

It is a matter of efficiency.

If you think about the fact that the UA should "[use the] values of that BODY element's background properties are their initial values", it makes sense to assign these values to the body tag.
If you use the html tag, UA may use a kind of fallback to display it, which is time consuming.
Of course, it's nothing for nowadays computers, but what about mobile devices, displaying let's said a background image with a cover background-size?

Furthermore, the order of html tags is a logical one, the link tags are defined in the head, in order to be used for the body and his childrens that come after. But if you apply a css rule to the html tag, the UA may go backward... And then forward.

So what are the advantages of specifying the canvas background for the BODY element? Quite nothing, for you, but some microseconds for the user, some microwatts for the client and the servers, but small streams make big rivers.

The w3c may have decided to do the opposite, it will have been ok too, it's just the purpose of a standard, that you make what a browser expects of you.

What? iOS does not respect the rules? (they can, they are apple). Don't change the correct way to do that, use [media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21456799/1387103).

Comment: "If you use the html tag, UA may use a kind of fallback to display it" What do you mean by "fallback"? The spec implies that whether you specify the background for the html element or body element makes no difference (assuming you only pick one) - immediately after the text that you quote, it says "the propagated values are treated as if they were specified on the root element."

Comment: @BoltClock, what I understand is that in the particular case of an html or xhtml document, the propagated values are treated as if they were specified on the root element (the "generic" case, see the begining of 3.11, I guess the special case of x/html vs other document is a central point). It have to make no difference (backgound for html vs body), in order to be more flexible, but, what I meant with "kind of fallback", is that there is a prefered way (body), and that it's better to follow this way for efficiency, in other words UA will check background on body first.